# Automated backups sql server IaaS

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure, azure-blob-storage

We have installed sql server on a virtual machine and we have registered the machine so that way SQL Server IaaS Agent Extension (SQLIaaSAgent) gets enable and runs on Azure virtual machines to automate administration tasks for sql server. One of those task is automate the backups as you can see the option in the next image

[image]

Now, to perform the automated backups we need an storage account, we have created that storage account and inside the storage account a blob container, but the problem we have right now is that when we are selecting the storage where we want the backups to go we can only select the storage account but not the container, So where are the backups going? we can't find them in the storage account, how can we be sure the backups are being made? and how can we select the blob storage in this feature?. thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

> An Azure storage account to use for storing Automated Backup files in
>   blob storage. **A container is created** at this location to store all
>   backup files. The backup file naming convention includes the date,
>   time, and database GUID.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/automated-backup

If you turn that feature off in the portal, you can still use the underlying engine feature [SQL Server managed backup to Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), which allows you to specify the container.